# Reading strings and numbers into an array

Tags: python, arrays, string

Thanks guys, that really helped. My main problem as you all pointed out was that I had 4 white spaces rather than a tab!

I have a textfile of the format:

```
string001    124.342
string002    235.111
string003    552.145
```

With a blank line at the bottom.

I just want to read this into an array. I thought that the best way to do this would be loadtxt from numpy, but when this didn't work, I went for genfromtxt, but couldn't quite get it to work either. This is what I have as my latest effort:

```
y = np.genfromtxt('1400list.txt',delimiter="\t", dtype=[('mystring','S10'),('myint','i8')])

print y
```

But I get the error:

```
rows = np.array(data, dtype=[('', _) for _ in dtype_flat])
ValueError: size of tuple must match number of fields.
```

Could anyone please help me to figure this one out?

Thank you!

Comment: which programming language you are using?

Comment: please add what language you are using to the question

Comment: What language are you using? Add a tag for the language if you want help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine here (although I suppose you want to use float dtype instead of integer one) with Python 2.7 and numpy 1.5.1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy

y = numpy.genfromtxt('1400list.txt', delimiter='\t',dtype=[('A', 'S10'),
('B', 'i8')])
print y
```

The output is:

```
vicent@deckard:/tmp$ python prova.py 
[('string001', 124L) ('string002', 235L) ('string003', 552L)]
vicent@deckard:/tmp$
```

Please, make sure that you are using tabs instead of spaces in your data file.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
f = open("text.txt")
items = []
for line in f.readlines():
    arr = line.split("    ")
    if len(arr) == 2:
        items.append((arr[0], float(arr[1])))
f.close()
```

Note that the numbers are floats, not ints. Also note that the last line has no entry, thus the `if len(arr) == 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the proper delimiter, that is, that your different columns are actually separated by tabulations and not hard spaces.

As an alternative, you could also use a tuple of integers as delimiters, if your initial file has some fixed formatting. In your case, that would be using

```
np.genfromtxt("text.txt", delimiter=(14,7), dtype=[('mystring','S10'),('myint','float')])
```

(Note that I corrected your `dtype`, using a `float` for the second element). The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html) will give you more details.